# Error when using On editing changed modifier on SecureField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Whenever I try to use the On Editing Modifier on a SecureField I get an error however when I change the field to a normal TextField, the error disappears. Below is the Textfield working properly.

```
VStack {
                    TextField("password", text: $password, onEditingChanged: { flag in
                        withAnimation {
                            self.formOffset = flag ? -150 : 0
                        }
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 2, alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
```

Here is where the SecureField gives me a ***Type of expression is ambiguous without more context***

```
VStack {
                    SecureField("password", text: $password, onEditingChanged: { flag in
                        withAnimation {
                            self.formOffset = flag ? -150 : 0
                        }
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 2, alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: SecureField has no `onEditingChanged`.